# Resolving first time exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, exception, nopcommerce

I am working on the nop ecommerce website, When i try to run the project, i am getting a continuous series of exceptions in the debug section of visual studio 2010 and the browser doesnt shows the website, on the bottom left of the browser , it displays waiting for localhost.
The exceptions are :

```
A first chance exception of type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' occurred in Autofac.DLL 
The thread '<No Name>' (0xb08) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Does anyone knows the way around , I am struggling to cope with as the website was running fine previously but suddenly it has stopped working :(

Answer (score 1):

I am currently having the same problem with Orchard. The problem seemed to occur when the beta of visual studio 2011 was installed, it has been suggested that it is being caused by a MVC or Razor assembly from the gac which is loaded and is taking over the ones which bin-ship.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/346791